# UICollectionView fixed Content Size

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, ios-extensions

I'm trying to create a keyBoard extension using UICollectionView (i try to use UIButtons but the keyBoard take long time to load so i'm trying to use collection view maybe it will be better).

My questions are:

1. what is better: to have a better responsiveness, should i use xib or code ?
2. My principle issue is that i can't fix the content size of the collectionView layout so i can't fix the height of cell (direction == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical)

here's how i'm trying to fix the cell height:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       return CGSizeMake(self.keyBoardCollectionView.frame.size.width/Keys_In_section.count, self.keyBoardCollectionView.frame.size.height/sections.count);
}
```

using this code the width is correct but not the height (this is cause direction == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical)

Answer (score 0):

for your first question both gives same responsiveness, but if you use storyboard designing will be easy.

for second one

http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1

just go through this link. it may helps you.